# Getting error while running python script file from .net web application

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, angularjs, sql-server-2012

I am trying to Execute python script from my .Net Web Application.
For this I have installed Python from nuget package manager.

Below is the Python Scrip to Insert a record in SQL Server database,

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=*****\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=TestDB;UID=sa;PWD=****')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("Insert into Results([EmailID],[Journey]) VALUES (?,?)", 55, "JourneyName") 
conn.commit()

Print("Success")
```

Below is the C# Code to execute above python file.

```
public string run_cmd(string strPath) //this must not be async
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.FileName = @"C:\Anaconda\python.exe";
            start.Arguments = string.Format("C:\\Users\\261866\\TestPYCode.py");
            start.UseShellExecute = false;
            start.CreateNoWindow = true;
            start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            start.RedirectStandardError = true;
            using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
        return "run till end";
    }
```

I am getting below error while executing above code,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\261866\TestPYCode.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyodbc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'
```

I have tried same with Iron Python, but still getting same error.

Note: Same Python code is running in Jupiter notebook, but not from visual studio,
pip pyodbc libs are already installed
, ODBC drivers for SQL are installed

Actually same kind of error coming if I write any "import * " statement in python script.

Comment: The problem is in the Python application. Inside the Python code, you are trying to import a module named `pyodbc` but it is not installed. So check that you can run the python script on its own. If yes, then check that you are using the same python installation (you can have several on a system)

Comment: Actually Same Python code is running in Jupiter notebook, but not from visual studio,
pip pyodbc libs are already installed , ODBC drivers for SQL are installed

Comment: this means that when you are running it from .net you are using a different installation of Python, as the module is not installed

Comment: I have installed Python 3.6 and iron python from nuget package manager.
please suggest the correct installation of python.

Comment: The Issue has been resolved, I was using wrong Python.exe,
Wrong Path was, C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe
Corrected Path is, C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe